# Parse - Facebook users being recreated everytime

Tags: ios, facebook, parse-platform

I'm using Parse.com + Facebook user and I'm noticing something unusual that has not been happening previously. A user creates an account via Facebook, logs in, logs out, logs in, logs out, and then when they try logging in, that user gets deleted and another user gets created. Why could that be?

Here is my signup/signin code:

```
-(IBAction)facebookSignIn:(id)sender{
    CLGeocoder *geo = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
    if(![CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled] || [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] == kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied ){
        UIAlertView *locationAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Oops!" message:@"You must have location services enabled for this app to work properly" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Okay", nil];
        [locationAlert show];
    }else{



        [PFFacebookUtils logInWithPermissions:_permissions block:^(PFUser *aUser, NSError *suError) {
            if(!aUser){
                NSLog(@"not fbook user because %@",[suError description]);

                if([[[suError userInfo] objectForKey:@"com.facebook.sdk:ErrorLoginFailedReason"] isEqualToString:@"com.facebook.sdk:SystemLoginDisallowedWithoutError"]){
                 UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Looks like you have Facebook authentication disabled! Go to Settings > Facebook > mySwapp and turn the switch ON"delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Okay", nil];
                    [alert show];

                }
                else{
                 UIAlertView  *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error Signing In/Logging In" message:[suError localizedDescription] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Okay", nil];
                    [alert show];
                }

            }
            else if(aUser.isNew){

                NSLog(@"User is NEW");
                 [[FBRequest requestForMe] startWithCompletionHandler:
                 ^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                 NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *user,
                 NSError *fbError) {
                 if (!fbError) {

                 NSLog(@"Facebook Request succeeded");

                 NSString *email = [user objectForKey:@"email"];
                 [aUser setEmail:email];

                 PFQuery *g = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Counter"];
                 PFObject *cool = [g getObjectWithId:@"gpKDgNhwhw"];
                 [cool incrementKey:@"users"];
                 [cool saveEventually];
                 NSString *username = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"blahblah%d",[[cool objectForKey:@"users"] intValue]];
                 [aUser setUsername:username];
                 PFInstallation *installation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
                 [installation setObject:aUser forKey:@"user"];

                 [aUser setObject:@NO forKey:@"text"];
                 [aUser setObject:@YES forKey:@"snew"];
                 [aUser setObject:@"All" forKey:@"prefState"];
                 [aUser setObject:@"All" forKey:@"prefCat"];
                     [aUser setObject:@YES forKey:@"fnew"];
                 _type = @"facebook";

                 NSLog(@"Right before geopoint search....");

                 [PFGeoPoint geoPointForCurrentLocationInBackground:^(PFGeoPoint *geoPoint, NSError *error) {
                 if(!error){
                 NSLog(@"Got current geopoint!");
                 CLLocation *myLocation = [[CLLocation alloc]initWithLatitude:geoPoint.latitude longitude:geoPoint.longitude];
                 [geo reverseGeocodeLocation:myLocation completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
                 if(!error){
                 CLPlacemark *pl = placemarks[0];

                 NSString *zip = [pl.addressDictionary objectForKey:(NSString *)kABPersonAddressZIPKey];
                 NSString *city = [pl.addressDictionary objectForKey:(NSString *)kABPersonAddressCityKey];
                 NSString *state = [pl.addressDictionary objectForKey:(NSString *)kABPersonAddressStateKey];
                 if(city == nil ||state ==nil){
                 NSLog(@"city or state is nil");
                 if(city==nil){
                 NSLog(@"city is nil");
                 }
                 if(state==nil){
                 NSLog(@"state is nil");
                 }
                 }
                 [aUser setObject:city forKey:@"city"];
                 [aUser setObject:state forKey:@"state"];
                 [aUser setObject:zip forKey:@"zip"];
                 [aUser setObject:geoPoint forKey:@"geopoint"];
                 [aUser setObject:@NO forKey:@"pref"];
                 [aUser setObject:@20 forKey:@"radius"];
                     [aUser setObject:@0 forKey:@"postCount"];

                 [aUser saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *perror) {
                 if(!perror && succeeded){

                 [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"registerMe" sender:self];                                          }
                 else{

                     CCAlertView *errorAlert = [[CCAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Oops!" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@. If you have already registered, please login regularly and go to the settings tab and switch on \"Link to Facebook\".",[[perror userInfo] objectForKey:@"error"]]];
                     [errorAlert addButtonWithTitle:@"Okay" block:^{
                         [aUser deleteInBackground];
                     }];
                     [errorAlert show];
                 }
                 }];
                 }
                 else{
                     CCAlertView *errorAlert = [[CCAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error getting Facebook data" message:[[fbError userInfo] objectForKey:@"error"]];
                     [errorAlert addButtonWithTitle:@"Okay" block:^{
                         [aUser deleteInBackground];
                     }];
                     [errorAlert show];

                 }
                 }];
                 }
                 else{
                CCAlertView *errorAlert = [[CCAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Facebook Sign In/Sign Up" message:[[suError userInfo] objectForKey:@"error"]];
                     [errorAlert addButtonWithTitle:@"Okay" block:^{

                         [aUser deleteInBackground];

                     }];


                 [errorAlert show];
                     NSString *ciid = [[PFInstallation currentInstallation] objectId];
                     [PFCloud callFunctionInBackground:@"logError" withParameters:@{@"installation":ciid,@"message":[suError description],@"place":@"Facebook Sign In/Sign Up"} block:^(id object, NSError *error) {
                         if(error){
                             PFObject * errorObj = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Error"];
                             [errorObj setObject:ciid forKey:@"installation"];
                             [errorObj setObject:[suError description] forKey:@"message"];
                             [errorObj setObject:@"Facebook Sign In/Sign Up" forKey:@"place"];
                             [errorObj saveEventually];
                         }
                     }];
                 }
                 }];


                 }

                 }];










            }
            else{
                NSLog(@"User is OLD");
                [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showMain" sender:self];                        }

        }];





    }

  }
```

and here is my logout code:

```
- (IBAction)goBackNow:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"gobacknow called");
    [PFUser logOut];

    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add more stuff to logout method. e.g.

```
[FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
[FBSession.activeSession close];
[FBSession setActiveSession:nil];

PFInstallation *installation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
installation[@"user"] = [NSNull null];
[installation saveInBackground];
```

Also remember to `[installation saveInBackground];` in your example